# Caddy reverse proxy server alerted internal error on attempt to relay TLS client hello

Tags: ssl, curl, proxy, reverse-proxy, caddy

I tried to let the *Caddy reverse proxy server* relay the *TLS handshake* between the client and the *back server*, but failed at very beginning when the proxy just received the *TLS client hello*. `Caddy v2.6.2` and `Curl v7.87.0` were under test below.

*/etc/hosts*:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost back-server.local proxy-server.local
```

*Caddyfile-back-server*:

```
{ http_port 2015 }
back-server.local:2016
respond "Hello, world!"
```

*Caddyfile-proxy-server*:

```
{ http_port 2017 }
proxy-server.local:2018 {
  reverse_proxy https://back-server.local:2016 {
    header_up Host {upstream_hostport}
  }
}
```

Initial tests were OK below.

```
$ caddy start --config Caddyfile-back-server
$ caddy start --config Caddyfile-proxy-server
$ curl https://back-server.local:2016
Hello, world!
$ curl https://proxy-server.local:2018
Hello, world!
```

The next test failed to relay the *TLS client hello* below.

```
$ curl --connect-to back-server.local:2016:proxy-server.local:2018 https://back-server.local:2016
curl: (35) ... internal error
```

According to the captured packets, `sni: back-server.local` was sent from the *TLS client hello* to *proxy-server.local:2018*, but the proxy returned *TLS server alert: internal error*, then closed the connection right away. No communication happened at all between *proxy-server.local* and *back-server.local:2016*.

What could be wrong and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Caddy server* as *reverse proxy* doesn't use [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) from *TLS client hello* for the related *TLS passthrough* to the *back server*, it's the job of *TLS forward proxy*. There's [Caddy L4](https://github.com/mholt/caddy-l4) plugin existing for *L4 routing* including *TLS SNI-based routing*.

Below was successful against this problem along with another *reverse proxy* [FRP](https://github.com/fatedier/frp) capable of acting as *TLS forward proxy* as well.

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1 localhost back-server.local proxy-server.local
```

*Caddyfile-back-server*

```
{ http_port 2015 }
back-server.local:2016
respond "Hello, world!"
```

*frps.ini*

```
[common]
vhost_https_port = 2018
```

*frpc.ini*

```
[common]

[TLS passthrough]
type = https
local_port = 2016
custom_domains = back-server.local
```

Then the test went through as expected. All the configuration files were put at PWD for simplicity.

```
$ caddy start --config Caddyfile-back-server
$ frps
$ frpc
$ curl --connect-to back-server.local:2016:proxy-server.local:2018 https://back-server.local:2016
Hello, world!
```